# Export decision tree

Tags: c++, c, matlab, tree

I analyse data with decision trees using Matlab.

If I want to use my trees with another platform or language (C, C++, java...), do you know if there is a smart way to do it?

The only thing I can export is a text file with the pseudo code of the tree:

```
 1  if a<5 then node 2 elseif a>=5 then node 3 else 1
 2  if b<1 then node 4 elseif b>=1 then node 5 else 1
 ...
```

I can write a cascade of "if, then, else" but I wonder if something better already exist.

Comment: if `a` is not < 5 then `a` is >= 5, there is no reason to use the `else 1` part, use `node = a < 5 ? 2 : 3;`

Comment: @AlterMann: The exception would be Not-A-Number which is neither >5 nor <=5.

Comment: @MSalters, I don't get you, NaN is not defined for integer types

Comment: @AlterMann: Usually not, no. But Matlab defaults to floating point.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest some model **JSON** or **XML**. Many parsers are available for each in most of languages and you can rebuild the Tree in next language for use.
Here is how I did it. [Decision Tree in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67856745/decision-tree-in-python/67856746#67856746)