# Decision Tree in Python

Tags: python, decision-tree

How to implement the idea of a DecisionTree in python.
In a TicTacToe game. Each gameState string represents the present situation

- 0 is Empty, 1 is Player 1 move, 2 is Player 2 move
  So a single ameState of 3x3 board looks like `'000200000'`
  MovesTree in game start to end looks like

```
['000200000', '000210000', '002210000', '002211000', '002211020', '102211020', '102211022', '112211022', '112211222']
```

**Question :**
How to add these moves (lets say from 1000 random games) in a DecisionTree so that if at any stage a gameState exists in a Tree, the subsequent moves are attached as next branch to that node.
PS. My objective is to find all the possible game paths for a tictactoe game and save them to a file. On reload the file is loaded to remake the DecisionTree and during game the computer could use it to decide after Human Player made a move.

- list is slow as there are expected to be 9! > 362880 moves except where game ended before all 9 moves made
- dict with each subsequent move as key and subsequent moves as value as dict key seemed most logical but I am unable to implement search, add methods

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement it as follows

```
def addGameMovesTreeToDataBaseTree(givenMovesTree:list):
    # Get global DataBaseTress
    global DataBaseTree
    # Get local copy of givenMovesTree
    MT = list()
    MT = givenMovesTree.copy() # Populate local MT from given givenMovesTree
    if len(MT) == 0: # Check if givenMovesTree is empty
        return
    elif len(MT) == 1: # Check if givenMovesTree has only last move
        Key = MT[0]
        if MT[0] in DataBaseTree.keys(): # Selected move exist as key in DataBaseTree
            pass # Dont do any thing
        else: # Selected move does not exisit in DataBaseTree
            Key = MT[0] # Store that move as Key
            DataBaseTree[Key] = [] # Add the key with value of empty list
    else: # Check if givenMovesTree has many moves
        if MT[0] in DataBaseTree.keys(): # Selected move exist as key in DataBaseTree
            Key = MT[0] # Store the move as Key
            if MT[1] in DataBaseTree[Key]: # Check if Next move exist in that Keys value
                MT.pop(0) # Remove the top move
                addGameMovesTreeToDataBaseTree(MT) # Go in deeper
            else:
                DataBaseTree[Key].append(MT[1]) # Add next move to value of Key
                MT.pop(0)
                addGameMovesTreeToDataBaseTree(MT) # Go in deeper
        else: # Selected move does not exist as key in DataBaseTree
            Key = MT[0] # Store the move as Key
            DataBaseTree[Key] = [MT[1]] # Add the key with value of next move
            MT.pop(0) # Remove the top move
            addGameMovesTreeToDataBaseTree(MT) # Go in deeper
```

Now I can sent it to JSON file and even load it at next time the program start

```
def saveToJSON(fileName:str):
    global DataBaseTree
    with open(fileName, mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        try:
            s = json.dumps(DataBaseTree, indent=2)
            f.write(s)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

def loadFromJSON(fileName:str):
    global DataBaseTree
    with open(fileName, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        try:
            DataBaseTree = json.load(f)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```